# How to get the close2() function to work in this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this JavaScript code. If I un-comment the code , close2() function doesn't work! What is the problem with it?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/files/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
/*
$("#popup-0").hide();
$("#popup-1").hide();
$("#popup-2").hide();
$("#popup-3").hide();
$("#popup-4").hide();

$("#popup-0").delay(100000).show(1000);
$("#popup-1").delay(6000).show(1000);
$("#popup-2").delay(30000).show(1000);
$("#popup-3").delay(18000).show(1000);
$("#popup-4").delay(12000).show(1000);

$("#popup-0").delay(150000).hide();
$("#popup-1").delay(110000).hide();
$("#popup-2").delay(70000).hide();
$("#popup-3").delay(68000).hide();
$("#popup-4").delay(52000).hide();
*/
function close2(i)
{
$("#popup-"+i).hide(1000);
}

</script>
```

Comment: `hide()` method may be in a queue

Comment: `$("#popup-"+i).hide({duration:1000,queue:false});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method **[`hide(duration)`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete)** will wait for the  animation queue provided to that element, you can avoid that by setting [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-options) option.

```
$("#popup-"+i).hide({duration:1000,queue:false});
```

---

or use **[`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop)** method to stop currently-running animation

```
$("#popup-"+i).stop().hide(1000);
```

---

or use `hide()` without any argument which also work as per docs

> Note that .hide() is fired immediately and will override the animation queue if no duration or a duration of 0 is specified.

Comment: tnx it works now , i didnt knew it has queue! :)

Comment: @Saeid : glad to help :)